# Change color of text when div is clicked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got this code snippet that's supposed to change the color of some text when you click on it. Here's the code:

```
<div class="change">CLICK ME</div>
```

I want the text color to change to either black, blue, red, #1d23f4, orange, or #123123 when I click on it. And, it should pick a color randomly from that list each time I click. How can I do that using vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: have you tried something already? are you using jQuery or vanilla Javascript?

Comment: I havent, Im not using either of those, never been into java or jquerry. Just html and css

Comment: you can't do this only with html or css because you need to handle the click event. this will be useful to you https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var arr = ["black","blue","red","#1d23f4","orange","#123123"];

   $(".change").click(function(){

      var random = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];

      $(this).css("background-color", random);

   });

});
```

I strongly recommend you to check out the jQuery documentation, it's very easy to handle click events with its API.

[jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript.  I changed the class to an id, added an onclick. I added all your colors into an array, and everytime the button is clicked, it get a random number thats as long as the array.  It then finds the div by id, and changes the color.

```html
<div onclick="clickMe()" id="change">CLICK ME</div>


<script>
 var colorArray = ["black","blue","red","#1d23f4","orange","#123123"]
  function clickMe() {
   var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * colorArray.length))
   document.getElementById('change').style.color = colorArray[randomNumber];
 }
  </script>
```

---

The advantage of my answer to @sebasaenz is that you don't need to load jQuery, or even a separate javascript file. Not that it's a better answer, just easier.